# Is it possible to use stream in Restler3 PHP?

Tags: restler

We are using Luracast Restler3 for our project. Some of our API calls return very large amounts of data. Might be a .CSV file of 100 00 lines or more, and of course takes even more memory as JSON or XML.

We will run out of memory in Restler formatter's if the result is returned as single array.
Is it possible to output these as streams instead or is there any other suggested solution for this. Paging is not possible due to limitations of our clients software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streaming is currently not supported by Restler, we are planning to add streaming support in the future version of Restler